# Sorting a Multidimensional Array by Text

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, text, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array in Javascript. I see plenty of explanations of how to sort one by number values, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort it by text.

The array that I want to sort looks like this:

```
var blocks = [
    {
        "heading": ["2013-10-1", "Chris", "11"],
        "content": "stuff 1"
    },
    {
        "heading": ["2013-10-3", "Zoe", "14"],
        "content": "stuff 2"
    },
    {
        "heading": ["2013-10-2", "Petey", "12"],
        "content": "stuff 3"
    }
]
```

I know I can sort this multidimensional array of objects like so on values that are numbers:

```
blocks.sort(
    function(a,b){
        return a.heading[2] - b.heading[2];
        }
    )
```

I'm not sure what the function I pass into the sort method would look like if I wanted to sort the array by the first or second value in the `heading` sub array since value at index 0 is a date and value at index 1 is text.

I tried to look up changing the date or text to a number and then evaluating it off of it's numeric value, but I wasn't able to find a way of doing so (nor do I know if that's the best way of approaching this). Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorting by text will sort alphabetically, your comparator function you pass will look exactly like the one you'd use for numbers. Which value are you actually trying to sort? Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to sort by the second value of the heading array, so it should be sorting the values "Chris", "Zoe" and "Petey". The block sort code is the code I tried for sorting. It does work for numbers (like the 3rd value in the heading array), just not for text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit]  I should point out that whilst the initial solution I suggested works, it's not a good solution because it's unnecessarily complex.

The `>` operator can be used for your purpose.  When comparing strings, string `a` is considered smaller than string `b` if string `a` comes before `b` in an alphabetically sorted list.

The only catch is that this is case sensitive and so upper case comes before lower case e.g. sorting the characters AaBbCc would give you ABCabc.

This means that you can just do this:

```
blocks = blocks.sort(function(a,b) { return a.heading[1] > b.heading[1] }
```

---

Previous answer:

Someone may be able to provide a more elegant solution, but this will work.

Note that `sort()` sorts alphabetically.  So all we need to do is make the sort() function work on the names of the people.

```
blocks = blocks.sort(
    function(a,b){

        var x = [a.heading[1], b.heading[1]].sort()

        if (x[0] == a.heading[1]) {return -1} else
        {return 1};
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
blocks.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.heading[0] < b.heading[0]) return -1;
    if(a.heading[0] > a.heading[0]) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Or just by simplifying the code above:

```
blocks.sort(function(a, b){
     if(a.heading[0] < b.heading[0]) {
         return -1;
     } else {
         return 1;
     }
     return 0;
});
```

You can also use the following:

```
blocks.sort(function(a, b){
    var heading_a = a.heading.toLowerCase();
    var heading_a=b.heading.toLowerCase();

    if (heading_a < heading_a) //sort ascending
        return -1 
    if (heading_a > heading_a)
        return 1
    return 0    //just return default value indicating there is no sort
});
```

If your data contain unicode strings then you should use the code above like this:

```
blocks.sort(function(a, b){
    var heading_a = a.heading[0].toLowerCase();
    var heading_a=b.heading[0].toLowerCase();

    return heading_a.localeCompare(heading_b);
});
```

This is just a sneak peak into sorting, it is just a quick example and I hope it helps.